# Parsing JSON file and store it fast

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

I'm developing an Android App.

When the app is open, it starts the new fragment with Recycler View.
All data for Recycler View is in a folder (user-choosen).

When the fragment starts, it list all DocumentFile[] in that folder, if mimetype is Jason, it start parsing and save it to an array (custom class CallLogItem).

My CallLogItem has several variables: name, phone, call duration, call direction.

Now I want to optimize my code: actually it parses all files with Gson in a loader. I have tried to save it in Shared preference with

```java
myPref.edit().putString(fileName, gson.toJson(my all)).apply()
```

And I check if

```java
myPref.getString(fileName,"").equals("")
```

All works but it's not much faster.

Eg.: on 420 files, 210 are JSON, and it takes 6 seconds to load from check if string exists in preference and parse values. Is there something faster?

This is my JSON:

```json
{

    "timestamp_unix_ms": 1698934275594,

    "timestamp": "2023-11-02T15:11:15.594+01:00",

    "direction": "out",

    "sim_slot": 1,

    "call_log_name": "Segr Telefonica",

    "calls": [

        {

            "phone_number": "42020",

            "phone_number_formatted": "42020",

            "caller_name": null,

            "contact_name": "Segr Telefonica"

        }

    ],

    "output": {

        "format": {

            "type": "OGG\/Opus",

            "mime_type_container": "audio\/ogg",

            "mime_type_audio": "audio\/opus",

            "parameter_type": "bitrate",

            "parameter": 48000

        },

        "recording": {

            "frames_total": 168960,

            "frames_encoded": 168960,

            "sample_rate": 48000,

            "channel_count": 1,

            "duration_secs_total": 3.52,

            "duration_secs_encoded": 3.52,

            "buffer_frames": 3840,

            "buffer_overruns": 0,

            "was_ever_paused": false,

            "was_ever_holding": false

        }

    }

}
```

When I save to SharedPreference, I only save some values like phone number, direction, duration, simslot.

Any help?

Thank you.

I have tried to save everything to SharedPreference.

--- EDIT ----
Here is my code:

Fragment:
in onCreateView:

```java
LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

my loader:

```java
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<List<CallLogItem>> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chrono.start();
        return new JsonFileLoader(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), storedUriString, contactList);
    }
```

JsonFileLoader:

```java
@Override
    public List<CallLogItem> loadInBackground() {
        List<CallLogItem> yourListOfItems = new ArrayList<>();
        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("JsonPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        if (storedUriString != null && !storedUriString.isEmpty()) {
            Uri treeUri = Uri.parse(storedUriString);
            DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getContext(), treeUri);
            Log.d("JsonFileLoader.loadInBackground", "treeUri: " + treeUri + ", pickedDir: " + pickedDir);
            if (pickedDir!= null && pickedDir.isDirectory()) {
                // Get the list of files in the directory
                String documentId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri);

                // Build a URI for the root directory
                Uri dirUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(treeUri, documentId);

                // Use ContentResolver to query for files in the directory
                Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(
                        dirUri,
                        new String[]{
                                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
                                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE,
                                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID
                        },
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        // Retrieve file information from the cursor
                        String fileName = cursor.getString(1);
                        String mimeType = cursor.getString(2);
                        Log.d("JsonFileLoader.loadInBackground", "File: " + fileName + ", Type: " + mimeType);
                        if (mimeType.equals("application/json")) {
                            if (preferences.getString(fileName, "").equals("")) {
                                Log.d("JsonFileLoader.loadInBackground", "File not parsed: " + fileName);
                                StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                                try {
                                    InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(3)));
                                    if (inputStream != null) {

                                        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                                        CharArrayWriter charArrayWriter = new CharArrayWriter();
                                        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                                        int bytesRead;
                                        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(bufferedInputStream);
                                        while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                            charArrayWriter.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        }
                                        content.append(charArrayWriter.toCharArray());

                                        reader.close();
                                        inputStream.close();
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                String jsonResponse = content.toString();
                                try {
                                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                                    CallLogResponse callLogResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, CallLogResponse.class);

[...]

                                    CallRegistration registration = new CallRegistration(contactUri, isContactSaved,
                                            callLogName, phoneNumber, phoneNumberFormatted, direction, timestamp, timestampDate.toString(), String.valueOf(durationSecsTotal), simSlot,
                                            audioFileUri.toString(), fileName, fileOutput);
                                    Log.d("JsonFileLoader.loadInBackground", "CallRegistration: " + gson.toJson(registration));
                                    editor.putString(fileName, gson.toJson(registration));
                                    editor.apply();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                //}
                                Log.d("File Info", "Name: " + fileName + ", Type: " + mimeType);
                            } else {
                                // Retrieve the JSON string from SharedPreferences
                                String json = preferences.getString(fileName, null);
                                Log.d("JsonFileLoader.loadInBackground", "json: " + json);
                                if (json!=null) {
                                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                                    CallRegistration callReg = gson.fromJson(json, CallRegistration.class);

                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.getDefault());
                                    Date timestampDate;
                                    try {
                                        timestampDate = sdf.parse(callReg.getTimestamp());
                                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                    }
                                    Uri contactIcon = null;
                                    if (callReg.getContactIcon() != null)
                                        contactIcon = Uri.parse(callReg.getContactIcon());
                                    Log.d("JsonFileLoader.loadInBackground", "Contact: " + callReg.getContactName() + ", Number: " + callReg.getPhoneNumber() + ", saved: " + callReg.getContactSaved() + ", default icon" + (contactIcon == null));
                                    yourListOfItems.add(new CallLogItem(contactIcon, checkIfContactIsSaved(callReg.getPhoneNumber()),
                                            getContactName(callReg.getPhoneNumber()), callReg.getPhoneNumber(), callReg.getPhoneNumberFormatted(), callReg.getDirection(), callReg.getTimestamp(), timestampDate, Double.parseDouble(callReg.getDuration()), callReg.getSimSlot(),
                                            callReg.getAudioFileUri(), callReg.getFileName(), callReg.getFileOutput()));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // Continue processing the file information as needed
                        Log.d("File Info", "Name: " + fileName + ", Type: " + mimeType);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                    // Close the cursor after processing
                    cursor.close();
                }
            } else {
                // Handle the case where the selected item is not a directory
                Log.e("Error", "The selected item is not a directory");
            }
        }  // Handle the case where the URI is not stored or is invalid

        // Sort yourListOfItems by timestampDate in descending order (newest first)
        yourListOfItems.sort((item1, item2) -> item2.getTimestampDate().compareTo(item1.getTimestampDate()));
        return yourListOfItems;
    }
```

CallRegistration:

```java
public class CallRegistration {
    private final String contact_icon_uri;
    private final boolean contact_saved;
    private final String contact_name;
    private final String phone_number;
    private final String phone_number_formatted;
    private final String timestamp;
    private final String timestamp_date;
    private final String duration;
    private final String direction;
    private final int sim_slot;
    private final String audio_file_uri;
    private final String file_name;
    private final String file_output;

    public CallRegistration(String contactIcon, boolean contactSaved, String contactName,
                            String phoneNumber, String phoneNumberFormatted, String direction,
                            String timestamp, String timestampDate, String duration, int simSlot,
                            String audioFileUri, String fileName, String fileOutputUri) {
        this.contact_icon_uri = contactIcon;
        this.contact_saved = contactSaved;
        this.contact_name = contactName;
        this.phone_number = phoneNumber;
        this.phone_number_formatted = phoneNumberFormatted;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.timestamp_date = timestampDate;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.sim_slot = simSlot;
        this.audio_file_uri = audioFileUri;
        this.file_name = fileName;
        this.file_output = fileOutputUri;
    }

    public String getContactIcon() {
        return contact_icon_uri;
    }

    public boolean getContactSaved() {
        return contact_saved;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contact_name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phone_number;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumberFormatted() {
        return phone_number_formatted;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public String getTimestampDate() {
        return timestamp_date;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public String getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public int getSimSlot() {
        return sim_slot;
    }

    public String getAudioFileUri() {
        return audio_file_uri;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return file_name;
    }

    public String getFileOutput() {
        return file_output;
    }

}
```

So in the first time I make a loop for every file in dir, if the file is stored I parse stored json, else I parse local json and save parsed to a new json.

Is there any better way to store those values I need and next read those values instead of parsing again the entire file?

Comment: It is pretty unclear what exactly you are saving in shared preferences. The whole json file?

Comment: @blackapps I'm saving the value I need for my app: timestamp, direction, simslot, phone number. Currently I save in preference parsed values like: gson.toJson (with a declared class which contains all elements I need), then on next time I only check if preference.getString is not empty so I parse the stored string (that is a JSON)

Comment: `I want to optimize my code:` Without you showing code its unclear what you expect of us to help you with optimizing.

Comment: Sure! I was out of home, will edit post!

Comment: Ok, we continu. 6 seconds at first pass and how many at following pases?

Comment: I found out that there is a problem with my code, but don't know if is related to JSON or my recycler view, will edit OP

Comment: Yes a lot of statemens are not ok. I tested the bunch and indeed for so much files its easily six seconds depending on the used device. What you could do better is just put the file uries in a list for the RecycleView. Then read and parse the json file only in on bind view. Just as you would load an image on the fly. So forget about putting in shared preferences.

Comment: `String fileName = cursor.getString(1);` That should be  String fileName = cursor.getString(0); And so on.

Comment: `...openInputStream(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(3)));` Well index 3 does not exist. The docId has index 2. But then you have a docId which will not work as you need the uri for the file here. How could you even measure the time as this will not run.

Comment: Yes, posted wrong code. Will try to parse on the fly, currently my recycler view shows items based on parsed files.
So contactImage, contactName, call duration, direction etc.